# how to get a post id to view that separately from facebook wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to view a post ID which I posted on facebook page's wall so I could observe its activity . Because facebook doesn't notify me when another one comment on that post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.prettyklicks.com/demo/fbjson.php

Then just run a jQuery setInterval to keep it live!

Answer (score 1):

If you created the post programmatically from your app by Graph API, as a response you should get a JSON object with the id of the post. You can save it into your database and use it to track comments.